# Android Studio: Rendering Problems

Tags: android, xml

This is some very basic stuff.
An Exception is raised during rendering:
java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag()Ljava/lang/String;

The XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that the issue is with the EditText object.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe check your `strings.xml` for `edit_message` and/or `button_send` values.

Comment: have you provide multiple language support ?

Comment: @onm118 Check if your edit_message string is large. Shorten it and try.

Answer (score 17):

This could be helpful for someone with the same issue. I use IntelliJ IDEA and I also had this problem...

After a while of playing with settings, I remembered I had this issue when I first started Android Development.

What caused this, was that I was developing for an Android Phone, but the rendering setting was set to Android Wear, after changing it to the non-wear setting, the problem was solved.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug on the release build environment: `Lava.Lang.Locale.toLanguageTag()`

It appears only after Java 1.7, and Android API which is based on Java 6 does not
support it.

Maybe this link can help you: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12649